# ArgumentError: The provided regular expression is using multiline anchors (^ or $)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have added password restrictions to my code. after that i am getting an error of:

```
ArgumentError: The provided regular expression is using multiline anchors (^ or $), which may present a security risk. Did you mean to use \A and \z, or forgot to add the :multiline => true option?
```

My **user.rb** file is

```
validates :password, :format => {:with => /^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9]).{6,}$/}
```

Comment: just replace them to \A \z pair

Comment: Can you please elaborate !!!

Comment: @the difference between ^$ and \A\z pairs is that the first matches the line-by-line (so require multiline mode, enabled to proper work), and second matches the whole string (begin and end consequently)

Comment: see here http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Anchors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between `^ $` and `\A \z` pairs is that the first matches the line-by-line, therefore requires multiline mode enabled to proper work, and the second matches the whole string, from begin to end consequently. Please see the definitions in [ruby docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Anchors).